# Make Two Views Share Click Feedback in Constraint Layout

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have this situation where I have a constraint layout. Within it lies two views. An ImageView and a TextView. When either of these Views is clicked, I want both to produce a feedback (text color change for textview and drawable tint in imageview) but I can't seem to think of a way to do these unless I put them inside another viewgroup.

Can someone show me how this could be done in constraint Layout? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`performClick()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()).

> performClick
>
> boolean performClick ()
>
> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

The idea is that when one view is clicked, your code will call `performClick()` on the other view. You will have to make sure that you inhibit any duplication of actions if the two views do the same function.

Other than doing this in code, I don't know of a way using just XML. There is the concept of a [`Group`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group) in `ConstraintLayout` but that just a way to control the visibility of the members of the group and does not extend to other properties.

I would use another enclosing view group unless you have a requirement not to. I just seems easier.

Comment: is there no other way of doing this without doing it in code? by doing this, I would need to handle the case where either is clicked and avoid the duplication of actions. Sounds too much for just a very simple thing. If that is the case, I'd rather add another view group to handle the click for both. What do think?

Comment: @ArchieQuiñones I would go with another view group. I just seems simpler.

Comment: I'll go that route then. I just though maybe there is a way when using constraint Layout. Anyway if you could edit your answer with that so I could mark it as accepted. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Group concept in  ConstraintLayout refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group ,[https://riggaroo.co.za/constraintlayout-guidelines-barriers-chains-groups/](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group) ,

**in java**

```
 Group group = findViewById(R.id.group);
        int refIds[] = group.getReferencedIds();
        for (int id : refIds) {
            findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // your code here.
                }
            });
        }
```

**Kotlin:**

```
        fun Group.setAllOnClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener?) {
                referencedIds.forEach { id ->
                    rootView.findViewById<View>(id).setOnClickListener(listener)
                }
            }
        Then call the function on the group:

            group.setAllOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                // your code here.
            })
```

Comment: I was asking about the click feedback here. Not really about the handling of clicks.